# Run Faster-rcnn on mobile iOS

Tags: tensorflow, coreml, object-detection-api, tensorflow-lite, coremltools

I have faster rcnn model that I trained and work on my google cloud instance with GPU ( train with google models API),
I want to run it on mobile, I found some GitHub that shows how to run  SSDmobileNet but I could not found one that runs Faster-rcnn.
real time is not my concern for now.
I have iPhone 6, iOS 11.4
The model can be run with Metal, CoreML, tensorflow-lite... 
but for POC I need it to run on mobile without train new network.
any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster R-CNN requires a number of custom layers that are not available in Metal, CoreML, etc. You will have to implement these custom layers yourself (or hire someone to implement them for you, wink wink).

I'm not sure if TF-lite will work. It only supports a limited number of operations on iOS, so chances are it won't have everything that Faster R-CNN needs. But that would be the first thing to try. If that doesn't work, I would try a Core ML model with custom layers.

See here info about custom layers in Core ML: http://machinethink.net/blog/coreml-custom-layers/